# Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof. Encountered: Map

Tags: json, dictionary, neo4j

I have a json file that I'm trying to import and build a graph.
The code is:

```
Cypher statement: //Load_JSON_Country
CALL apoc.load.json("/Users/mpinto/.Neo4jDesktop/relate-data/dbmss/dbms-1f5f63ad-bba8-4673-8d16-2a3bd7299f65/import/countries.json")  YIELD value
MERGE (longitude:Longitude {longitude: value.longitude})
WITH * WHERE value.native IS NOT NULL 
MERGE (native:Native {native: value.native}) 
MERGE (timezones:Timezones {timezones: value.timezones}) 
MERGE (translations:Translations {translations: value.translations})
MERGE (name)-[:has_longitude]->(longitude)
MERGE (name)-[:has_native]->(native)
MERGE (name)-[:has_timezone]->(timezones)
MERGE (name)-[:has_translations]->(translations)
```

And the error is:

> Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof. Encountered: Map{zoneName -> String("Asia/Kabul"), gmtOffsetName -> String("UTC+04:30"), abbreviation -> String("AFT"), gmtOffset -> Long(16200), tzName -> String("Afghanistan Time")}.

I thinks is because of the json file:
"

```
timezones": [
            {
                "zoneName": "Asia\/Kabul",
                "gmtOffset": 16200,
                "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+04:30",
                "abbreviation": "AFT",
                "tzName": "Afghanistan Time"
            }
        ],
```

I don't know how to put this in a cypher statement...
Thank you for your help!

Comment: As you are trying to 'MERGE' a ':Timezone' label you need a unique attribute in your input data. Not sure what the overall structure of your json is, but : do you want to create a ':Timezone' node for each entry in that json list? If so, I guess the 'zoneName' lends itself as a good unique value?

Comment: @bert that's exactly it!